# Application level optimization

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

what is the best way to call a stored procedure and still have a very low response time in asp.net ? i have tried filling a dataset from an adapter:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbm.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlcom = conn.CreateCommand();

        sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcom.CommandText = "";
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SOME_ID", Session[IWConstants.SessionAccountID]));
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@END_DATE", ""));
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FILTER_OPTION", ""));
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@START_DATE", ""));
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcom);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqlDA.Fill(ds);

        csvDataTable = ds.Tables[0];
```

and this block is giving me 11,000 plus milli seconds in response is there a better way of doing it ??

Comment: Have you tested the execution time of the Stored Procedure on its own? Maybe it isnt the C# code that is the issue

Comment: How about using an entity model?

Comment: nopes i tested this block using dottrace and the sp call its self takes 1 second to respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you have written is definitely one of the most efficient ways.** I assume that you acrually set the `CommandText` to the name of your stored procedure.

**Your response time** probably has to do with either **network topology** or **available sql server resources**. (Assuming your sp excutes on very short time when tested directly on the sql server.)

Check out the second table on this page http://ormeter.net/ to see how much an ORM adds to execution time if that is what you are considering that as an option.

If you want to micro-optimize what happens in client code you could use a datareader instead of filling a dataset. That has slightly lower overhead, but in comparison to accessing the database it's usually negligable.

Comment: Thanks great answer it has helped me i was in a confusion about it. might be that i ran the performance tests using dottrace and it was running the site reference in local webserver that might have had caused the delay. thanks again.